# Typescript: Get correct answers type from inquirer questions array

Tags: typescript, inquirerjs

I have an [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) questions array like the following:

```
const prompts = [
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'foo',
        message: 'Enter a string',
    },
    {
        type: 'number',
        name: 'bar',
        message: 'Enter a number',
    },
] as const;
```

I would like to obtain the type of the answers object that inquirer is going to give me after calling `prompt()`. My current approach looks like this:

```
import { Question } from 'inquirer';

export type PromptAnswersFor<T extends ReadonlyArray<Question>> = {
    [key in T[number]['name']]: string;
                                ^^^^^^
//            what do I need to put here to make it work?
};
```

However, I don't know how to type the value on the right-hand side of the `PromptAnswersFor` type. At the moment it will always go to `string`.

Ideally, I'd want `PromptAnswersFor<typeof prompts>` to be `{ foo: string; bar: number }`. I'm pretty sure it's possible, but I don't know how?

Edit:
I'm able to infer the answer type for a single question like this:

```
type AnswerType<Q extends { type: string }> = Q extends { type: 'input' } ? string
                                            : Q extends { type: 'number' } ? number
                                            : Q extends { type: 'password' } ? string
                                            : Q extends { type: 'confirm' } ? boolean
                                            : never;

const inputQuestion = { type: 'confirm' } as const;
type T = AnswerType<typeof inputQuestion>
// -> boolean
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you say you want it to be `{ foo: string; bar: number }` but `prompts` states that the type property of `foo` is `input`, so should that be `string`?

Comment: @VVS correct, `input` is the typeof `inquirer` prompt, it indirectly indicates a `string` result. There's actually more prompt types which I've excluded for brevity: `"input" => string, "password" => string, "number" => number, "confirm" => boolean, ...`

What matters for the question is that I want `PromptAnswersFor` to correctly infer the typescript type based on the type of questions inside `prompts`, based on an arbitrary mapping.

Comment: I've edited my question to show how I'm doing the mapping at the moment.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68852423/13847690) might be helpful for you?