# Create a Record type with fixed length keys from string array of keys in another interface

Tags: typescript

This is the minimal code example. I have an interface named `Foo` which has property `one` which accepts an array of the object type.

```
interface Foo {
    one: {
        key: string;
       // more properties
    }[]
}
```

Here the type of `key` is a string.

I want to create a Record type where keys would be of string literal union type which we would take from the array of `key`  of one property in Foo type and values can be any string type.

I am getting issues in creating that type.

Contrived Example:

```
const example: Foo = { 
    one: [{ key: "mykey1" }, {key: "mykey2"}, {key: "mykey3"}]
}

const A = {} as Record<string, string>; // as of now I did it like this
// I need to strongly type this constant.

example.one.map(el => {
  A[el.key] = "anything" // contrived example 
})
```

Comment: You can't annotate `example` as `Foo` and then ask the compiler to remember the string literal values from `example.one[someNumber].key`; that's just `string` in the definition of `Foo`.  If you want the compiler to keep track of it, you need `example` to be of a type which represents those string literals, and then you can use `Record<typeof example["one"][number]["key"], string>` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbdadw).  If this works for you I'll write up an answer.  If not, please elaborate on what's missing.

Comment: Perfect!! One thing I didn't understand about adding `asFoo` function. If you write this answer explaining the same would be helpful 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Annotating a variable as `Foo` throws away the key information you need**

The main obstacle here is that when you [annotate a variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) with a (non-[union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)) type, like `const example: Foo = ...`, the compiler will treat that variable as being of that type regardless of what value you initialize it with.  And so any more specific information about the initialized value, such as the [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"mykey1"`, will be thrown away.  The definition of `Foo` has just `string` as the `key` property of the elements of the `one` array, and so `string` is what you'll get if you try to inspect the variable's type:

```
const example: Foo = {
    one: [{ key: "mykey1" }, { key: "mykey2" }, { key: "mykey3" }]
};
// const example: Foo
type KeyType = typeof example["one"][number]["key"]
// type KeyType = string, oops
```

So you really don't want to annotate `example` (unless you want to manually write out the full type with all the information needed).  Instead you should try to get the compiler to *infer* the type of `example` in such a way that it has the information you care about, while still being seen as assignable to `Foo`.

---

**Simply omitting the annotation also throws this key information away**

If we simply leave off the annotation, that's also not sufficient:

```
const example = {
    one: [{ key: "mykey1" }, { key: "mykey2" }, { key: "mykey3" }]
};
// const example: {  one: {  key: string; }[]; }
type KeyType = typeof example["one"][number]["key"]
// type KeyType = string, oops
```

Again, it's just `string`.  That's because the default heuristics for inferring variable types tends to widen any string literal properties to just `string`.  Properties are sometimes reassigned, and the compiler has no idea that you don't intend to write `example.one[0].key = "somethingElse"`.  And so `string` is the type it infers instead of `"mykey1"`.  We need to do something else.

---

**A `const` assertion will preserve the key information, but it's not compatible with `Foo` anymore**

If you want to tell the compiler that you are not going to modify the contents of `example` and that it should try to infer the most specific type possible, you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the initializer:

```
const example = {
    one: [{ key: "mykey1" }, { key: "mykey2" }, { key: "mykey3" }]
} as const;
/* const example: { readonly one: readonly [
    { readonly key: "mykey1"; }, 
    { readonly key: "mykey2"; }, 
    { readonly key: "mykey3"; }
    ];
*/

type KeyType = typeof example["one"][number]["key"]
// type KeyType =  "mykey1" | "mykey2" | "mykey3", hooray!
```

Now `example` is inferred to be an object with a `readonly` property containing a `readonly` array of objects with `readonly` properties whose values are the string literals we care about.  And so `KeyType` is exactly the union of string literals we want.

That's great, and we'd be done here, except for one wrinkle.  The inferred type of `example` is not assignable to your `Foo` as defined.  It turns out that [`readonly` arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#improvements-for-readonlyarray-and-readonly-tuples) are not assignable to mutable arrays (it is the other way around), and so this happens:

```
function acceptFoo(foo: Foo) { }
acceptFoo(example); // error! one is readonly
// -----> ~~~~~~~
```

---

**Maybe you should redefine `Foo` to be compatible with a `const` assertion**

Are you ever going to add or remove elements from a `Foo`'s `one` property?  If not, then the easiest solution here is to just redefine `Foo`:

```
interface Foo {
    one: readonly { // <-- change to readonly array type
        key: string;
        // more properties
    }[]
}

acceptFoo(example); // okay now
```

If you don't want to make that change, then you need some other solution.  And even if you do, leaving off the annotation and using `as const` has the side effect that `example` really might not be a valid `Foo`, and you wouldn't catch it until you tried to use it as a `Foo` later:

```
const example = {
    one: [{ key: "mykey1" }, { key: "mykey2" }, { kee: "mykey3" }]
} as const; // no error here

/* const example: { readonly one: readonly [
    { readonly key: "mykey1"; }, 
    { readonly key: "mykey2"; }, 
    { readonly kee: "mykey3"; }
    ];
*/

acceptFoo(example); // error here
```

The third element of `one` has a `kee` property instead of a `key` property.  That's a mistake, but there's no error at the `const example = ...` line because nothing says it has to be a `Foo`.  You get an error later when you treat it like a `Foo`.

This might be acceptable to you, or maybe not.  If it is, then we can stop here. If not, read on:

---

**Or you can make a generic helper function to infer a `Foo`-compatible type that also preserves key information**

Another idea instead of using `as const` is to make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper function that guides the inference process.  At runtime it would just return its input, so it looks like a no-op.  Here's one way to do it:

```
interface FooWithKeys<K extends string> extends Foo {
    one: {
        key: K;
        // more properties
    }[]
}
const asFoo = <K extends string>(fwk: FooWithKeys<K>) => fwk;
```

The `FooWithKeys<K>` type is an extension of `Foo` where the keys in `one` are known to be `K`, which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be a subtype of `string`.  A type `FooWithKeys<"a" | "b">` is assignable to `Foo`, but the compiler knows that the keys are `a` or `b` and not just `string`.

The `asFoo()` helper function will look at its input and infer a type for `K` that is consistent with it.  Since the type parameter `K` is constrained to `string`, the compiler will try to infer string literal types for it if possible.

Let's see it in action:

```
const example = asFoo({
    one: [{ key: "mykey1" }, { key: "mykey2" }, { key: "mykey3" }]
})
// const example: FooWithKeys<"mykey1" | "mykey2" | "mykey3">
```

Looks good.  Now we can get the key type as before:

```
type KeyType = typeof example["one"][number]["key"]
// type KeyType =  "mykey1" | "mykey2" | "mykey3", hooray!
```

and make your `A` dictionary:

```
const A = {} as Record<KeyType, string>;
example.one.map(el => {
    A[el.key] = "anything"
})
```

And `example` is still seen as a `Foo`:

```
acceptFoo(example); // okay
```

And if we made any mistake with `example`, we'd get an error right there:

```
const example = asFoo({
    one: [{ key: "mykey1" }, { key: "mykey2" }, { kee: "mykey3" }] // error!
    // -----------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'kee' does not exist in type
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-CR9ns3r5X6yDU1Ayds2W-dohguCEOQ7rKDQjCsJwuiiJI1gyNYSjwmoqhaKgfCiOGliUEOVhRAQwSNWebU3jEvBJJNXg5IU5TGrU9gNK0gBZDA8DAcQQV02h9JtPwAvtUz8u0uyxFxJVTydb1HL9ZzA3c5QQy88M6yjPzAjRuNQhixboozSDs3CzIfEnQkzFDMxEtrcTWPUP4XE0rQUGg+goF2560upyFBCqvsu2yizCuUZXl0isqc3qzHWZW6I6qKhrVM52KJFa66RA67gutQ9DMNNbDbvuhjTvOy62soN36NYRiaagJ62PFrBJelj6ni1V5UAAcXYFsADV6BgF2EaoPTrUM1GjwdbHKGsuR8eUQnfX9FyjCDcnPJqWWs4Mlh2CB6DThgAAePopjoEAW1LJUAD5u6gXvSyMvPTPpqzcT6EuRDLpyA1c6uRApuuqZ8ktbUCTvh9HxVXTkAfiIAd1Ec6W7bzuB8o-wh4YM-FG8yNIRjLeGKnyg6WC5qgI5mqiDs3TAAnmfNyI-nSsNC+8lW4SA7pOJabNkhrRatEAess5q3hjPeIaQchQvhFO+cUuxpqhhlH+PqUJmYQSNjQ9am0tDbVlvtZ2wI-YnVIr4C6VFTDsIYo9YWtI3pEFlulL4-l+YlhQMpRwWAWyd0oekQep5hoADoQiqIgGAOAjFPABCHp-FAXwLBQE8KoyIVgYzRDACAIgCk5DRFsOA0wwlvqoF1ICRA0Foaw3EKWQxkCg5vxgERQxDMEyG3zGFYBv9wL-ygFzdaRJnrqHYloZCnovTqAALS5LyfkgphSinFIKUPAAfhUypVTKkFxSSgAA8hsAAVlATCKBPDyXoGAPRWjOwWXgK0jADBxx-BPthCupN0g2JbCgAA5OIKAsyUBtlgCgP44I3Aw3BDQAaMtgzOK8g8IAA)